# I am trying to bind the dropdownlist to UI using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

function BindUpdateDetails(Degid) {

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "DesignationMaster.aspx/BindUpdateDesignationMaster1",
    async: false,
    data: "{'Desigid':'" + Degid + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {

        var jsonData = result.d;
       // console.log(jsonData);
        $('#txtDesignationId').val(jsonData.Table[0].DesignationId);
        $('#txtDepartmentCode').val(jsonData.Table[0].DesignationCode);
        $("#txtDepartmentCode").prop('disabled', true);

        $('#txtDesignationName').val(jsonData.Table[0].DesignationName);
```

/*dropdown*/            $('#ddlDepartment').val(jsonData.Table[0].DepartmentId);

```
        $('#chkIsActive').prop('checked', jsonData.Table[0].IsActive);    

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Details Not Fetch');
    }
});
```

Comment: We need more information before we can answer this. For instance, what's going wrong? Is it the Ajax POST that's failing, or is it failing somewhere in the success block?

Comment: Only dropdown  $('#ddlDepartment').val(jsonData.Table[0].DepartmentId); is not working rest  everything is working smoothly

Comment: Does the response definitely have a DepartmentId specified in Table[0}? If so, does the dropdown actually have the corresponding value?

Comment: someone suggested me to pass dynamic in values in dropdown in same line of code. how to do that??\

Comment: $('#ddlDepartment').val(jsonData.dynamic.Department); is this a correct way to do?

Comment: So, what is the method that the post request is calling supposed to be returning? If it's proper JSON then you could do something along the lines of `var json = JSON.parse(results.d)` then you could do something along the lines of: `$('#ddlDepartment').val(json.TableName.DepartmentId)`. Without knowing the structure of the response and how you're initially creating the dropdown list I can't really say more.